# Problems with coding Preference Screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

i have a big Problem with this Code:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

private LinearLayout rootView;


private LinearLayout titleView;

private ListView preferenceView;

private TextView textView;



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(R.string.tx_einstellungen);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setTextSize(20);

    titleView = new LinearLayout(this);
    titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 45));
    titleView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);
    titleView.addView(textView);
    titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    preferenceView = new ListView(this);
    preferenceView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    preferenceView.setId(android.R.id.list);

    PreferenceScreen screen = createPreferenceHierarchy();
    screen.bind(preferenceView);
    preferenceView.setAdapter(screen.getRootAdapter());

    rootView.addView(titleView);
    rootView.addView(preferenceView);


    this.setContentView(rootView);

    setPreferenceScreen(screen);

}


private PreferenceScreen createPreferenceHierarchy() {

    PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    PreferenceScreen lang_screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    // Screen preference

    lang_screen.setKey("language_pref");
    lang_screen.setTitle("Sprache");
    lang_screen.bind(preferenceView);
    root.addPreference(lang_screen);

    // Example of next screen toggle preference
    CheckBoxPreference nextScreenCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setKey("next_screen_toggle_preference");
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setTitle("");
    nextScreenCheckBoxPref.setSummary("");
    lang_screen.addPreference(nextScreenCheckBoxPref);


    return root;

}
```

The First PreferenceScreen is a nice white screen with a blue line on the top and in the line we have the Text "Einstellungen" in english "Preferences" in color white.

However when i click on "Sprache" the next prefcreen is black and there is an android Titlebar.... i want to create more "under-prefscreens" and they all have to be white with these blue line on the top.

PLEASE HELP

Thankx Alex

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Android 2.1u1.

If you use multi-level preference screen the Light theme is not propogated to next level screens. For higher SDK 2.2 and above it works perfectly fine. The issue is also on some devices. Unfortunately no solution yet for this apart from leaving the theme as dark.